# Excel Multiple Selection Count

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, excel-2003

I want to know how to count some cells in excel based on its contents.

For example, I have something like this:

```
aa
ad
sa
fafv
xcv
aaw
gadf
aae
```

I want to count all if it begins or contains "aa".

How can this be acheived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If list is in range A1:A8 use

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A8,"*aa*")  ' for contains

=COUNTIF(A1:A8,"aa*")  ' for begins with
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked. I'll be accepting this as answer in 10 minutes.